# Error "SCRIPT 1028 Expected identifier, string or number" with IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, babeljs, browserify

I'm using **Browserify** to transpile my JS code to be sure the final code is compatible with most browsers, and all is working perfectly with *Chrome* and *Firefox*.

But I'm using a package (`dot-prop`) that **IE11** does not seem to like due to the name of some functions like `get` in `get(obj, path, value)` (https://github.com/sindresorhus/dot-prop/blob/master/index.js) and generate the classic error:

```
SCRIPT 1028 Expected identifier, string or number
```

Yet I'm using a whole bunch of **transpilation tools**:

```
browserify --extension=.jsx --transform [babelify --presets=es2015,stage-2,react --plugins=[babel-plugin-transform-es3-member-expression-literals,babel-plugin-transform-es3-property-literals]] --transform [es3ify] GUI/index.jsx --outfile dist/GUI/bundle.js
```

But as far as I understand the tools consider the code as valid, which it is for most browsers indeed.

I'm probably missing a transpilation component who might transform the `get(...)` in something like `"get": function(...)`.

**Am I missing something?**

**If the issue is real, can it be fixed with such a component?**

**Or should I fix the code myself, and if so what is the best way of doing so?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was more subtle: as `dot-prop` is a dependency stored in `node_modules` by default it is ignored by ***Browserify*** hence not passed to ***Babel*** through ***Babelify*** for transpilation.

Until I find a clean way of asking Browerify to handle only this dependency I've found a simple workaround: **pre-generating a transpiled version of the dependency**.

I have a dedicated NPM script in my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "precompile": "babel node_modules/dot-prop/index.js --out-file precompiled/dot-prop.js",
```

And I reference the resulting transpiled module in place of the original one.

e.g. in `someModule.js`:

```
const dotProp = require("../precompiled/dot-prop");
```

Hopefully it will help someone else. :-)